# SVG donut-shape with access of both circles

Tags: javascript, svg

I want to create an SVG donut shape (circle with another empty circle inside). I want to be able to access & resize both circles, eg via their id attributes. This will allow for animation.

I have considered three approaches but none are that great:

- complex path: does not allow for access of the inner circle via #id
- outline stroke: possible but complicated for my purpose (would have to reposition as I increase stroke)
- clippath/mask: Doesn't work like a compound path, only an outer box

Is there a way of doing this?

Comment: What's wrong with using a `circle` and its `stroke`?

Comment: @Zach it's a headache to maintain the cx/cy position of the circle as you move the inner & outer independently of each other

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably the easiest way would be with masks.

If you are working with a set of discrete donut sizes, you could use CSS and a mask for each size:

```
<svg width="500" height="500">
    <defs>
        <mask id="bigmask">
            <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="white"/>
            <circle cx="250" cy="250" r="50"/>
        </mask>
        <mask id="smallmask">
            <circle cx="250" cy="250" r="150" fill="white"/>
            <circle cx="250" cy="250" r="100"/>
        </mask>
    </defs>
    <circle id="donut" cx="250" cy="250" r="200" mask="url(#bigmask)"/>
</svg>
```

CSS:

```
#donut:hover
{
    mask: url(#smallmask);
}
```

[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/bLkkpjwc/)

Unfortunately you can't modify the size of circles with CSS. "r" is not (yet) a property that can be manipulated with CSS.  So you will need to either use SMIL (SVG) animation, or manipulate your mask circles with javascript:

```
<svg width="500" height="500">
    <defs>
        <mask id="donutmask">
            <circle id="outer" cx="250" cy="250" r="200" fill="white"/>
            <circle id="inner" cx="250" cy="250" r="50"/>
        </mask>
    </defs>
    <circle id="donut" cx="250" cy="250" r="200" mask="url(#donutmask)"/>
</svg>
```

JS

```
$("#donut").mouseenter(function(evt) {
    $("#outer").attr("r", 100 + Math.random() * 100);
    $("#inner").attr("r", 100 - Math.random() * 50);
});
```

[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/bLkkpjwc/1/)

Comment: Thx a lot! I didn't know masks could be composed of multiple ID'd components

Answer (score 1):

Although BigBadaboom's answer is the best way IMO, if you want to use a compound path, it's possible to animate by rewriting the path's `d` attribute each frame like this:

```
// get svg path coordinates for a ring
ring:function(x, y, ir, or) {
    var path  =
          'M'+x+' '+(y+or)+'A'+or+' '+or+' 0 1 1 '+(x+0.001)+' '+(y+or) // outer
        + 'M'+x+' '+(y+ir)+'A'+ir+' '+ir+' 0 1 0 '+(x-0.001)+' '+(y+ir) // inner
        ;
    return path;
}
```

Comment: For another variant of that see http://xn--dahlstrm-t4a.net/svg/path/donut-shop.html.

Comment: interesting! nice demo too